# Unable to compare String from query parameter in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, uri, query-string

I'm new to node.js and javascript.
Can you please tell, why this comparison is not working?

My route handler code:

```
friends = [{  
id: 0,
name: "Dan"
}]

app.get("/search", (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.name) {
  let friend = null;
  Object.keys(friends).forEach((id => {
    if (friends[id].name === req.query.name){
        friend = id;}
       }));

  res.send(friend);     
}//end of outer if block
});
```

And my search query is:

```
localhost:3000/search?name="Dan"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have checked the typeof both friends[id].name & req.query.name and both are of String type.
However, when I print them on console it gives Dan & "Dan" respectively.

Comment: just figured out the problem. I was actually comparing "Dan" with ""Dan""(query String). If I change my query string to name=Dan it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figured out the problem. I was actually comparing `"Dan" with ""Dan""`(query String). If I change my query string to `name=Dan` it works just fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the `friends` variable to anything before you do the `Object.keys(friends)` function call. Therefore, it has nothing to create the keys from and the `.forEach()` loop is never executed.

Comment: actually it was a global variable and was on top.Sorry! let me just edit my code.

Comment: @AmitGupta => Your global variable is an Array of Objects. You can't do the `Object.keys()` function on an Array. Are you attempting to check to see if the `.name` property is equal to the `req.query.name` property?

Comment: No, I want to compare strings.

Comment: It doesn't work, even if I change my loop as: 
`friends.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item.name);
       if(item.name == req.query.name){
        console.log('success');
       }`